# Why are links from my solutions manual ineffective?

Tags: cross-referencing, amsbook, xr

I have the following four files.  The book is created using file myBook.tex given by

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\includeonly{data}
\begin{document}
\input{data}
\end{document}
```

together with data.tex given by

```
\lipsum

\label{myBookPage}This is a test.
```

Finally, the solutions manual mySolutionsManual.tex is given by

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{myBook}
\includeonly{data, solutionsManualdata}
\begin{document}
\input{solutionsManualdata}
\end{document}
```

where solutionsManualdata.tex is

```
\lipsum

Go to page~\pageref{myBookPage}.
```

All four files are in the same directory.  Both pdfs are two pages in length.  I have both open within my PDF reader, which is WinEdtPDF.  There is a link within the solutions manual pdf.  I want to click on it in the hope that it would cause the book pdf to be activated (displayed within the reader) and "This is a test" within that display to appear at the very top.  Instead, clicking on the link causes the solutions manual pdf to itself be shifted to the top of its own first page.
Are my expectations somehow unrealistic?  Incidentally, documentclass amsbook clearly is not the problem.  Using documentclass article gives the same result.  Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Comment: why should your link find a target in an independant pdf? Nothing in your code tells it in which file it should look.

Comment: I have attempted to address this issue in the emended question but what I have done does not work.

Comment: your solution document doesn't load hyperref and so has no links at all. And use xr-hyper instead of xr.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.   I thought that, for mere labels as opposed to hyperlink/hypertarget, xr would be sufficient.  In any case, xr-hyper made for no change that I can see.  I still have no links, it seems.

Comment: What is `\includeonly` meant to do?

Comment: You need to read `xr`'s documentation.

Comment: Load also hyperref.